# Change values in a column based on previous/following rows

Tags: r, dataframe

Imagine I have a table such as:

```
        ScaleDown ScaleUp
1           0        0
2           1        0
3           0        0
4           0        1
5           0        0
```

And what I want to do is perform a scale up or down function on a column so that values will be altered to reflect a positive entry that just happened(scale down) or positive entry coming up(scale up).
So the table should end up looking something like this:

```
        ScaleDown ScaleUp
1           0        0
2           1       0.33
3          0.66     0.66
4          0.33      1
5           0        0
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: how are you calculating the values in the final result?  (where does the 1/3, 2/3 come from?)

Comment: `read.table('clipboard', header = TRUE)` will work for this data.

Comment: Please tell us the answer for foo$ScaleDown <- c(0,2,3,0,4) such that we can imagine what are you looking for

Comment: @mnel had no idea about `'clipboard'` argument. Thanks for pointing that out!!

Comment: There are various ways to do what you want, but `filter` is a fairly general function that has the ability to do things like that.

Comment: This is just an example but the table I have is very similar to the top example just way bigger. The point is I'm not sure how to calculate the values for the other results. What I want is to pass a column in and then for each row to know if a 1 is coming up in the next(for this example 2) rows and then increment towards that(scaling up), and vice versa for scaling down ad then output the results like the second table I showed.

Comment: all the entries given will be either 0's or 1's so for foo$ScaleDown <- c( 0,1,0,0,0 ) the result would be (0, 1, 0.66, 0.33, 0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Sample Data
df <- data.frame(scaleDown=c(0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1), scaleUp=c(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0))

# Function call with mapply
mapply(adjust, df, c(F, T), MoreArgs=list(rate=3, rounding=2))

#           scaleDown scaleUp
#      [1,]      0.00    0.67
#      [2,]      1.00    1.00
#      [3,]      0.67    0.00
#      [4,]      0.34    0.00
#      [5,]      0.00    0.00
#      [6,]      0.00    0.34
#      [7,]      1.00    0.67
#      [8,]      0.67    1.00
#      [9,]      0.34    0.50    <{~~ 
#     [10,]      0.00    1.00
#     [11,]      1.00    0.00
```

function:

```
adjust <- function(vec, reverse=FALSE, rate=3, rounding=3) {

  if (reverse)
    vec <- rev(vec)

  # add a dummy "1" to end of vec for calculating ends. Will be removed
  vec <- c(vec, 1)


  len <- length(vec)
  indx <- which(vec[-len] != 0)
  ends <- c(indx[-1L], (length(vec) + rate))

  ranges <- sapply(ends-indx, min, rate)
  subtr <- round(vec[indx]  /  ranges, rounding)

  for(i in 1:length(subtr)) {
    for (j in (ranges[i]-1):1) {
      vec[indx[i] + ranges[i]-j] <- vec[indx[i] + ranges[i]-j-1] - subtr[i]
    }
  }

  # remove dummy element
  vec <- vec[seq(len-1)]

  if (reverse)
    return(rev(vec))
  return(vec)
}
```

Comment: @mnel, the up & down is used to calculate the interval size. In the rest of the code I'm only using one the down index

Comment: This looks really great thanks a lot for your help. It's past midnight here so I'll have to check it out in the morning but if all works accordingly you've earned some points.

Comment: Actually as an added bonus, what if.... the column went c(0,1,0,1)? The resulting column would need to be c(0,1,0.5,1) if you catch my meaning. Food for thought, good night all.

Comment: @EvilWeebl, hence the `interval`.  This should work.  If you find any issues, please let me know.

Comment: Hiya, sorry im just now getting a brief look over this. Just a question but are you assuming here that the raming is done between a positive value in one column to a negative column in the next column? sounds confusing but I find it strange at intervals <- (upIndx - downIndx + 1) seeing as the columns are not related to each other. Pretneding Scaleup doesnt exist for now, in ScaleDown I would like the values to ease off after hitting a positive value(which yours seems to show but fear it may be a coincidence).

Comment: Maybe something like finding the distance between each positive value using diff(which(df$ScaleDown !=0)). If the ScaleDown column is c(0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1) then the result should look like c(0,1,0.66,0.33,0,0,1,0.66,0.33,0,1). diff(which(df$ScaleDown !=0)) would result in (5,4).

Comment: @EvilWeebl. The rate can easily be adjusted.  Can you be more exact/explicit in how you want the rate to be calculated?

Comment: @EvilWeebl, created an argument for rate that you can adjust as needed. Also added an argument for Reverse, so that you can call the function with mapply as in the example above.

Comment: This looks brilliant! I'll be sure to have a play with this. Thanks a lot!